# How to disable Verbose Error Messages of soap web services?

Tags: web-services, iis, soap, owasp

How to disable Verbose Error Messages of soap web services?

I have one web method with some para.

Example Req:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <GenerateTestRequest xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <sId>1@!aB</sId>
            <mobileNum>12345678</mobileNum>
            <srcType>1</srcType>
        </GenerateTestRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

When an unexpected input was supplied into `sId` para instead of Int32, Then the web service returned an exception within the response content.

Example Res:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:DeserializationFailed</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-SG">The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:sId. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Int32. The value '1@!aB' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.</faultstring>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I don't want to display response content of exception message. Is there any way to turn off stack trace or exception details?

Comment: You can try the errorpage component in IIS, and change the Edit feature settings on the right to the first option.

Comment: @TheobaldDu Thank you for advice. I tried as you suggest but still get same result.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to turn off stack trace or exception details?

Yes, by doing proper error handling for the SOAP web service.

A SOAP request can receive back a successful SOAP response or can receive back an unsuccessful response in the form of a SOAP Fault. People unfortunately focus on the successful cases only and let the framework they are using handle other problems.

Because SOAP is a protocol any exception on the server needs to be converted to a proper Fault response. This needs to be done by the developer by catching any exception and building appropriate Fault responses out of them, with only the needed data inside. For security reasons of course that data can't contain stacktraces or others sensitive information. But like I said, people often neglect to handle the error cases, and the framework can't build custom Faults, it can only build a SOAP fault with details from the exception that occurred, exposing it to the client.

You didn't tag this `WCF` but the schema namespace on the error code says `windowscommunicationfoundation` so I'll assume that's the web service framework. You can replace all exception messages with a generic error message by setting `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` to false (I think for your service it is set to true right now). See here for details: [either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server](https://forums.asp.net/t/2072459.aspx?either%20turn%20on%20IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults%20either%20from%20ServiceBehaviorAttribute%20or%20from%20the%20serviceDebug%20configuration%20behavior%20on%20the%20server)

Or, you can do proper error handling and define and document the possible Faults a client can receive and convert any exception to one of those Faults. You can start reading here: [Specifying and Handling Faults in Contracts and Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/specifying-and-handling-faults-in-contracts-and-services)

If you are using any other web service framework or library, the idea is the same, the documentation to read will be different.

Comment: Thank you @Bogdan for your helpful answer.  Yeah I forgot to add `wcf` tag. By setting `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` to false is getting turn off stack trace. But I think I still have to do customized error handling. Again thank you for your error handling link.

Comment: I got it by setting `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` to false for stack trace info disable. However short error message still disclose. The problem is that it is not even hit to web method if I put wrong input type to web method. In this situation, how do I write custom error handler? or is there any way to disable fault exception short message also? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to realize that every API has errors and exceptions and a SOAP web service is no different. At some point your clients will encounter a SOAP Fault from your service. The idea is to do proper error handling and to create your own fault contracts (like the link in my answer shows - you have to follow that documentation or other tutorials about fault contracts). When you define your own fault contracts you can display whatever error code and error message you like for the client to see, instead of generic ones or stacktraces coming from the framework.